# Как записать данные из бд в интернете в свою локальную бд?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

Я разрабатываю приложение МЕНЮ для кафе и ресторанов, и проблема такая возникла с сохранением данных. Нужно чтобы приложение работало без подключения к интернету, чтобы вся информация хранилась в своем локальном БД, на телефоне, а при подключении к интернету - стягивал всю измененную информацию с БД, который будет находиться на хостинге. Через админку будем добавлять товары, рубрики и изменять содержимое БД которое находится на хостинге. А при подключении к интернету, приложение просто обновит свое БД.

Я думаю сделать так: Поставить на хостинг mysql, а в приложение sqlite и сделать между ними обмен. Это возможно? Я не смог нагуглить никакую информацию на счет обмена этих двух баз. 
Или как лучше правильно реализовать оффлайн режим приложения? Записей не будет больше 5000 в БД.

Comment: Что у Вас не получается? Чем плохо обмениваться между базами любыми стандартными форматами данных как то: xml, json, cvs, и.т.д. ? Делается за час максимум.

Comment: т.е получается я смогу развернуть в приложении базу данных sqlite и в него заносить информацию с базы данных mysql через обмен json например?

Comment: Почему нет? :) Вариантов много. Естественно, на стороне сервера, где стоит mysql должна быть какая то поддержка выдачи данных в таком формате. Может это и не самое красивое решение, зато простое и наиболее легко реализуемое. Страшнее давать приложению прямой доступ к удаленной БД. Тут уже безопасность...

Comment: *А при подключении к интернету, приложение просто обновит свое БД.* Вы прикиньте объём своей БД, особенно после конвертации в текстовый формат для выгрузки. А то может статься, что будете полчаса новую БД качать, а потом лимит трафика превысится... Организуйте на сервере фиксацию изменений по времени и подготовку файлов корректировок в совместимом формате (скажем, ежесуточно или там еженедельно), приложение, зная, когда последний раз обновляло БД, скачает готовые пополнения, потом запросит и получит индивидуальную выгрузку изменений после крайнего обновления, и потом всё это подгрузит в БД.

Comment: @Akina что мешает сделать фильтрацию результатов за диапазон дат "от сих до сих"?

Comment: Среди возможных текстовых форматов предлагаю также рассмотреть и формат готовых SQL-запросов для корректировки таблиц БД. загрузил и тупо выполнил построчно, всё.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Ничто не мешает - если в таблицах вообще есть такое поле как "Дата изменения записи". Что, кстати, не факт. Равно как не факт, что запись вместо удаления помечается в поле валидности как дохлая (у удалённой записи даже наличие поля даты корректировки не поможет - запись-то удалили).

Comment: @Akina у нас нет такой подробной информации, чтобы это предполагать. Я бы на стороне сервера взял бы что нибудь типа django, и серверную часть запилил бы очень быстро со всеми возможными вариантами :) И не mysql, а postres :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен `SyncAdapter` - в принципе на этом можно и нужно заканчивать весь ответ, но я таки напишу общую схему:

1. На стороне сервера пишем *RESTful* веб сервис, который на запросы отдает JSON
2. На стороне клиента пишем `SyncAdapter`, который отправляет на сервер запросы, принимает json и парсит их складывая в SQLite
3. Далее на стороне клиента пишем `ContentProvider`, который работает поверх засинханной SQLite базы и кажет что-то юзе

[Пример реализации SyncAdapter](https://github.com/jbeuckm/Android-SyncAdapter-JSON-Server-Example/tree/master/src/com)

Вкратце все это называется Android REST design pattern - погуглите и будет вам счастье.

P.S. Оставлю открытым вопрос как люди пишут *приложение МЕНЮ для кафе и ресторанов* - очевидно на заказ не понимая основных принципов и не зная стандартные паттерны проектирования - видимо, поэтому у нас до сих пор нет возможности толком сделать в онлайне заказ в ресторане :)

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ! буду пробовать!

Comment: можно ли вместо SyncAdapter использовать Retrofit? Ретрофит легче в реализации?

Comment: У вас каша в голове. `SyncAdapter` и retrofit выполняют разные задачи: retrofit - http клиент,  а `SyncAdapter` выполняет задачу синхронизации, для которого можно воспользоваться вызовами retrofit

Comment: я сейчас по первому пункту разбираюсь, я учусь писать RESTful веб сервис по этим урокам - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33magO6kfoU          Я в правильном направлении иду? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Направление движения правильное, но вы выбрали "тяжелый" путь, RESTful сервис можно написать на чем угодно, урок рассказывает про генерацию сервиса через Spring... Судя по всему вы же веб девелопер, так что можете сгенерить сервер на чем угодно, на PHP или Node.JS - здесь главное понять синтаксис get/post/put/delete запросов которые будет высовывать наружу сервер + ну и плюс структуру json данных, чтобы на стороне клиента они правильно ложились

Comment: Вот генерация сервиса на вашем любимом django https://habrahabr.ru/post/160117/

Comment: К сожалению я не веб девелопер, я пол года изучаю джаву и андроид, вот и взялся за свой первый проект. Попробую тогда на джаве запилить по этим видео урокам, спасибо за ответ!